# How to open the linux embedded keyboard device in qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt, embedded-linux

In Qt, I need to access the keyboard device of Embedded Device (Linux). If a key is pressed in embedded device I need to print which key is pressed in Qt.

I tried with `QKeyEvent` its worked with PC keyboard but not with Embedded device, so I searched and found `QWSKeyEvent` for Linux embedded device from this [link for `QWSKeyEvent`](https://qt.developpez.com/doc/qtextended4.4/tut-deviceexample/) and subclassed `QWSKeyboardHandler` and `QKbdDriverPlugin`

```
ExampleKbdHandler(const QString &device = QString("/dev/input/by-path/platform-600000.ohci-usb-0:2:1.0-event-kbd"));    
kbdFd = ::open(device.toLocal8Bit().constData(), O_RDONLY, 0);
```

i am getting below error when i try to open the keyboard device,

```
examplekbdhandler.cpp:16: error: ‘::open’ has not been declared
         kbdFd = ::open(device.toLocal8Bit().constData(), O_RDONLY, 0);
                 ^
```

Comment: Did you include `fcntl.h` header? Documentation: https://linux.die.net/man/3/open

Comment: Please confirm that you are using Qt4

Comment: didnot include previously, as you said now i downloaded fcntl.h file and included but still it is asking for , _mingw.h: No such file or directory, then i downloaded _mingw.h from net and again its showing error like io.h file is missing. I have a doubt whether i downloaded correct file

Comment: @FrankMeerkötter i am using QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.7

Comment: From your link i tried to download fcntl.h but not found so i downloaded from another link